# Upload php script rename function

Tags: php, function, upload

I have this PHP script and was wondering if somebody could help me with one question.

Lets say I upload a file named "me.jpg", What will the file be renamed to after it is uploaded?

```
 if($_FILES['q35']['tmp_name']){
        $file_ext=eregi_replace("^(.*)\.(.*)$","\\2",$_FILES['q35']['name']);
        $file_ext_35 = strtolower($file_ext);
        if(in_array($file_ext, $whitelist)) {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['q35']['tmp_name'], $url[server].'/images/'.$image_folder.'/selfie.'.$file_ext_35);
        }
```

Comment: @Josh The problem is I can't try it, that's why I've posted it here. hoping that somebody who's experienced in PHP could just give the answer by reading the code ^_^

Answer (score 0):

First you should replace eregi_replace by preg_replace. eregi_replace seems to deprecated. As for your question, let's assume your code would work, your picture's name would still be 'me.jpg'